# How to TabBarController display differents Items?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabitem

On my `firstViewController` I have a `tabbar` that contains my `firstViewController` and a `helpViewController`.

When I click on a button from the `FirstViewController`, I push a `NewViewController`. But, when this view is pushed, I want to change the content from the `TabBarController` to display other ViewControllers, like `infoViewController`, `optionViewController` and `NewViewController`. Is that possible?

The First Image represents my application. The `FirstViewController` has a button that will push the `NewViewController`. When the user clicks this button, I want that my app shows what is in the second image. Is possible?[image: My problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!!This app uses navigationController and TabBarController!!
Using the storyboard I saw each piece of the app, then I had the Idea: Insted of pushing the `NewViewController`, how about push a `tabBarController`? When the user clicks the button, the app will push the `tabBarController` with 2 TabController`s.

Just add New File to your project, sub classed UITabBarController. Then add this code to the init method of your `tabBarController`: `self.hidesBottonBarWhenPushed = YES;`

On `ViewDidLoad` just alloc and init what views you want to display on the tabBar and

`self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc1, vc2, vc3, nil]];`

Working fine here :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible (I just did a proof of concept in Xcode). Assuming that you are using storyboarding, you need to make your initial view controller a `UINavigationController` otherwise you won't be able to use the push segues. Then, make the first `UITabBarViewController` the root view controller of the navigation controller. Put an entirely new `UITabBarController` into the storyboard, and then put a `UIButton` into the `firstViewController` and link it via a push segue to the new (second) `UITabBarController`.

When you tap the button the old tab bar will slide off, and the new one will slide on.

Here's an example of how it all looks:
[image]

Comment: Glad it worked. If this answer did solve your problem then I would appreciate if you could please mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can nest TabBarControllers. But that would look strange. And the first TabBar wouldn't be changed. Pushing a TabBarController into a TabBarController is not possible because TabBarController does not support pushViewController. Thats only possible with a NavigationController.

Anyhow you can change the content of the TabBar completely programatically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you put this code on the init methode, you will have just one TabBar:  `self.hidesBottonBarWhenPushed = YES;` .